# How do I tell my boss I want to start applying to other places?

Tags: management, internship

I joined a start up very early ( a month old) and have done everything from setting it up with Google, to product management, inventory management, understanding the technology, solving pricing matrices, and much much more (e-mail marketing, advertisements, etc.).

I originally joined as a part time intern and was told I'd go full time after I finished school.

After finishing school I was told that "There's not enough work for you to do at the company to become a full time employee."

I'm still working my intern hours (20 hours a week) and need to start finding a full time position. The problem is is that my boss and the culture is awesome. I can work from home some days, and my boss is really positive. I don't want to leave this company but I can't afford to stay for much longer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I give additional notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/should-i-give-additional-notice-period)

Comment: @CKM I'm actually the 'only' employee believe it or not. My boss is actually the CEO and brought me on to get the business up and running. He works 40+ hours a week full time at his current job and just gives me work to do to help the start up

Comment: I wouldn't call myself the CEO under those circumstances, unless you want to be laughed at :) Founder is far more appropriate.

Comment: Just a hint. As you are the only employee, don't you see a chance to become the second-most important person in this company after some time? Perhaps in some months you regret to have left this company. Talk to your boss, don't simply leave.

Comment: Using the title "CEO" in a side-gig company staffed by one part-time intern is a gross misnomer. If your boss un-ironically calls himself that, I would say it's time for you to quietly find other work and move on to bigger and better things when you're ready. If you like the work, however, it won't hurt to ask for more hours and more duties.

Answer (score 12):

Don't tell your boss anything. Look for a new job that will provide the income you need. When the time comes give your boss notice. If you still feel very strongly that you wish to stay there negotiate then. Tell your boss how much you want to stay. If they can keep you they will and if not then not.

Answer (score 7):

You should never tell them that you are looking for another job.

What you should do is to talk to him and tell him that you love that place and you really want to be there, but you need to work more hours and to earn more money. If they really want you, they will try to get you that position. Sadly, sometimes it's not possible, and you will have to leave, but if you stated that before is a plus for you in the future when maybe they open up a position that fit your needs.

As a last advice, if you find another job and after that they offer you something better (a counter-offer), do not accept, because that means they were lying to you.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

Either find a full time position and give up this great job.

or

Find another part time job to supplement your income.

I've often held down more than one job. One strategy is to have them totally different, a physical type job and one which involves more brain work. This works well for some people. If you think about going this route because you want to see the end product of all your work or just enjoy the challenges, then ask the boss how many hours he can guarantee you and get contracted. Then start looking for a supplementary job.