# Tomorrow is my annual performance review with my manager : should I tell him I want to quit this career?

Tags: career-development, review

I'm 28 and work in IT as a system administrator. Tomorrow, I'll see my manager to have my annual review. He will ask me how I see my career evolution.

I clearly want to quit IT but I clearly have no idea what's my next career move...

It's been more than a year that I'm trying to figure out what I want to do.

Should I tell him I don't see myself continuing in this career or should I keep it to myself to save some time so I can find something next ? I could have stayed more but the salary is ridiculous compared to market and they won't hear that. That's not motivating me to stay. I'll probably even change company before changing field. I would benefit from a €5000 yearly raise.

EDIT : I wouldn't mind getting replaced, that would allow me to be put on unemployment wage, it would give me time for training in anything else than IT and our national employment agency has lot of trainings available. I don't know which one to choose yet ( of course, it would have been too easy).

Comment: Never, ever, ever tell your company anything like this.  Never tell them you are thinking of leaving, or, any similar concepts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I give additional notice period?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13047/should-i-give-additional-notice-period)

Answer (score 11):

You should never quit a job unless you have something lined up. And you should never let your employer know that you're leaving, or searching for a new job. There's too much risk and not enough benefit.

Otherwise you risk having no income, and being reliant on savings (if you have any) and potentially being laid off before you decide to quit.

In addition, if you don't find something immediately, while you're explaining to potential employers *why* you quit, you're also going to have to explain the gap in unemployment.

tl;dr have something else lined up before you decide to quit.

Comment: With some managers in some companies, you can tell them things like this and it might help.  I wouldn't do it with lots of managers I've had.  Err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the country, it could be very hard or very easy to fire you. So as a general rule of thumb, if it is not about changing role/moving in the company, I would not advise to say anything if you have nothing planned.

Unless your job is so taxing on you that you cannot have time or energy to think about what to do after, then you could consider telling them.

Answer (score 0):

> I wouldn't mind getting replaced

then ask the boss how you can help the company in another position.

If he is in anyway sympathetic, and likes you as an employee, ***and*** - here's the catch - thinks that he can move you within the company, to the benefit of the company, then he will discuss possibilities with you.

Normally, I totally agree with "never quit (or invite firing) until you have a new job lined up”. However, since you mention a low wage, this may be feasible, depending on location, which you failed to state. For instance, in Germany I believe that you would get 80% of your last salary as unemployment benefit …

… if you quit. ***On no account resign***, as you will not be eligible for unemployment benefit in most countries.

If you are looking for a total career change, that can be difficult, to say the least. But if, for instance, you made a side-step into [Dev Ops](https://theagileadmin.com/what-is-devops/) , which is latest buzzword to chase, that could be ***extremely*** lucrative. You could easily command Eur 500 per ***day*** as a freelance contractor (and get some long term contracts). See also [DevOps toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps_toolchain). Just search for it on JobServe, to see what I mean.

Btw, if/when you do resolve this, please come back and let us know how it turns out. Good luck :-)